# On scroll recyclerview item Background color changed when recylcerview scroll

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, recyclerview-layout

I want to change `Recyclerview` item background color on my condition but when I scroll  background color automatically changed   I know    `holder.setIsRecyclable(false);`  but I don't want to set `holder.setIsRecyclable(false);`

and I know

```
 if(item.value == 1){
    // do something
    } else{
      // do something
   }
```

but i want to do using nested if else

```
           if (feetInt > 0 && feetInt < 4) {
                ((PatientViewHolder) holder).rlClientItemMain.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(mContext, R.color.player_list_green));
            } else if (feetInt >= 4 && feetInt < 6) {
                ((PatientViewHolder) holder).rlClientItemMain.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(mContext, R.color.player_list_yellow));
            } else if (feetInt == 0 || feetInt >= 6) {
                ((PatientViewHolder) holder).rlClientItemMain.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(mContext, R.color.player_list_red));
            }else{
                ((PatientViewHolder) holder).rlClientItemMain.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(mContext, R.color.player_list_grey));
            }
```

Comment: please share your complete adapter

Answer (score 2):

Instead of changing color on `feetInt` maintain a flag in your object class and on the basis of particular flag change your background color

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are not updating the value of feetInt for every single object in list. That's why you are facing this issue.

Update feet int value in list for different different position, you will get the desire result.

Also, remove getItemViewCount() and setIsRecyclable(). These are not required at all. Also, share your code for more specific answers.

Answer (score 0):

```
holder.setIsRecyclable(false);
```

Comment: It will be great if you could explain your solution and how it solves the OP's problem

Comment: RecyclerView uses one view multiple times. user Scroll the list then remaining off screen item will display. for stop the Recycle item you can use setIsRecyclable(false)

Comment: If you read the question though, the OP does not want to use this specific property